# Grant MODIFY on "All Subfolders and Files" with icacls, but only give Read to top level folder

Tags: windows, scripting, powershell, file-permissions, icacls

One of our Windows servers that has some user folders on it has some pretty screwed up permissions. What I want it for `SYSTEM` and `Domain Admins` to have full control of all folders. I want the users to have read only on the top-level folder (which is their home folder) and modify on all subfolders and files. This can easily be accomplished through the GUI, but I can't figure out how to script it.

I'm calling icacls from my PowerShell script, because get-acl and set-acl are a major PITA. If I have to use them, I'm not opposed to it, but I imagine that calling icacls will be easier. This is the relevant code that I have to far:

```
icacls.exe $folder /grant '$domain\$user:(OI)(CI)(M)'
icacls.exe $folder /grant 'SYSTEM:(OI)(CI)(F)'
icacls.exe $folder /grant '$domain\domain admins:(OI)(CI)(F)'
```

As you can see, I'm giving modify to the user for everthing with `icacls.exe $folder /grant '$domain\$user:(OI)(CI)(M)'`. I can't figure out how to make that Modify apply only to subfolders and files while granting read-only to the top level folder.

The desired permission structure would look like this (just for clarity):

```
-Users  
--M  
---Marra (read only to me)  
----Documents (Modify)  
----Scripts(Modify)  
----Etc (Modify)
```

What is the right icacls syntax for this, or how can I do it natively in PS with set-acl?

Comment: If you can set the desired permissions in the GUI, then just do this manually for one folder, and afterward see how they look like with "icacls $folder".

Comment: You should make it more clear that $folder refers to $server\Users\M\Marra

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the first line of your script to the following to have it apply only to subfolders and files.

```
icacls.exe $folder /grant "$domain\$user:(OI)(CI)(IO)(M)"
```

Then apply this to the top folder.

```
icacls.exe $folder /grant "$domain\$user:(R)"
```

Comment: That's accurate to answer my question, but I need the users to be able to create files and sub-folders. To do that, I needed to use (R,WD,AD) for the top-level.

Comment: wouldn't the OP want /grant:r to replace any previouly granted explicit permissions? If it's screwed up, don't  you want to replace what's there?

Comment: @JJS, `/grant:r` probably wouldn't do anything useful in this case, because it only removes permissions that match the specified inheritance flags.  I find the `/reset` option simpler to use.

Answer (score 0):

Grant inheritable modify permission, and set uninheritable denial to delete the folder itself:

```
icacls folder /deny  user:d
icacls folder /grant user:(oi)(ci)m
```

This gives them full rights inside the folder, but they cannot modify the folder itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
icacls $folder /c /grant $domain\$user:(OI)(CI)(X,RD,RA,REA,WD,AD,WA,WEA,DC,RC)
```

This grants MODIFY access to all files and subdirectories, but not delete access to $folder itself.